# Problema para guardar datos con CKEDITOR PHP Y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de insertar datos de un CKEDITOR a una base datos mysql con php, pero estoy intentado capturar esos datos a través de distintos modos que encontré en la web, pero no lo consiguo insertar el contenido del CKEDITOR en un campo de la BD: htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, pero no sé de qué modo puedo capturar e insertar esos datos. les dejo el código que utilizo, y si me pudieran ayudar a lograrlo.

```
//Primero a través de un js guardo los datos:

var editor= CKEDITOR.instances['editor'].getData();
//y así envío el dato con ajax y metodo GET
```

Luego en el archivo PHP, mediante el método GET para insertar:

```
caracteristica_producto=$conexion->real_escape_string($_GET['editor']);
```

Comment: hola, bienvenido a SOes, podrías indicar si te da algún error? por favor agrega mas información. Te dejo un link quizás te ayude a formular mejor tu pregunta: [¿Como hacer una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Para capturar los datos del `ckeditor`, lo puedes hacer con `php`

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="texto" id="editor1"></textarea>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
        {
            lang: 'es',
            skin: 'office2013',
            allowedContent: true,
            ignoreEmptyParagraph: false,
            enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
        });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $contenido = addslashes($_POST['texto']);
?>
```

Y si lo haces con `ajax`, tiene que ser por post

**AJAX**

```
var data = $("#idFormulario").serialize();
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "url",
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {

      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ckeditor guarda html si o si, asegúrate que el campo donde se guarda sea preferentemente VARCHAR y no apliques ningún filtro a la variable que recibe el contenido del ckeditor, guárdalo tal cual, osea no uses htmlentities ni nada de eso y obviamente envía mediante POST.

Answer (score 0):

Ya probaste con addslashes?

```
$conexion->addslashes($_GET['editor']);
```

Comment: `addslashes` ya es una funcion propia de `php`, por lo que hacer `$conexion->addslashes` es un error y no es apta como respuesta

Answer (score 0):

validaste que tu variable editor contenga algo?
Lo primero que debes hacer es validar hasta que parte esta viajando tu información; es probable que no estes capturando correctamente los datos del control.